# How to access and edit variables inside functions in python

Tags: python, function, variables

Im new(-ish) to python and I made a game today which after I finished I realised I'd made a big mistake :

inside the functions I had to access and edit variables which where also accessed and changed in *other* functions and maybe in the future outside the functions. And I don't know how to do that.

I've researched for a long time and found very few things that might solve the problem, I've tried a few, but they haven't  worked and I don't understand how to use others.

Could you please try to help me with the problem and if you spot others please tell me, as Im not too good at debugging :(

Here is the code below, its quite big (I've put the variables I need to access and change in bold):
    from random import randint
    print ("Ghost Game v2.0")
    print ("select difficulty")

```
score       = 0
alive       = True
difficulty  = 0
doors       = 0
ghost_door  = 0
action      = 0
ghost_power = 0
                #define the function 'ask_difficulty'
def ask_difficulty() :
    difficulty = input ("Hard, Normal, Easy")
    set_difficulty()



                # define the function 'set_difficulty' which sets the            difficulty.
def set_difficulty() :
if difficulty == 'Hard' or 'Normal' or 'Easy' :
    if difficulty == 'Hard' :
        doors = 2

     elif difficulty == 'Normal' :
         doors = 3

     elif difficulty == 'Easy' :
         doors = 5

else:
    print ("Invalid input, please type Hard, Normal, or Easy")
    ask_difficulty()



            # define the function 'ghost_door_choose' which sets the ghost door and the chosen door


def ghost_door_choose(x):
    ghost_door = randint (1, x)

    print (doors + " doors ahead...")
    print ("A ghost behind one.")
    print ("Which do you open?")

    if doors == 2 :
        door = int("Door number 1, or door number 2...")
        if 1 or 2 in door :
            ghost_or_no()

        else :
            print ("Invalid input")
            ghost_door_choose(difficulty)


    elif doors == 3 :
        door = int("Door number 1, door number 2, or door number 3")
        if 1 or 2 or 3 in door :
            ghost_or_no()

        else:
            print ("Invalid input")
            ghost_door_choose(difficulty)


   elif doors == 5 :
        print("Door number 1, door number 2, door number 3, door number 4,     or door number 5.")
        if 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 in door :
            ghost_or_no()

        else:
            print ("Invalid input")
            ghost_door_choose(difficulty)


                 # define the function 'ghost_or_no'
def ghost_or_no() :
    if door == ghost_door:
        print ("GHOST!!")
        print ("Initiating battle...")
        battle()

    else:
        print ("No ghost, you\'ve been lucky, but will luck remain with you...")
       score = score + 1
        ghost_door_choose(difficulty)

                # define the function 'battle' which is the battle program
def battle() :
    ghost_power = randint (1, 4)               # 1 = Speed,  2 = Strength,  3 = The ghost is not friendly, 4 = The ghost is friendly

    print ("You have 3 options")
    print ("You can flee, but beware, the ghost may be fast  (flee),")
    print ("You can battle it, but beware, the ghost might be strong (fight),")
    print ("Or you can aproach the ghost and be friendly, but beware, the ghost may not be friendly (aproach)...")
    action = input ("What do you choose?")

    if flee in action :
        action = 1

    elif fight in action :
        action = 2

    elif aproach in action :
        action = 3

    else :
        print ("Invalid input")
        battle()

    if ghost_power == action :
        if action == 1:
            print ("Oh no, the ghost\'s power was speed!")
            print ("DEFEAT")
            print ("You\'r score is " + score)
            alive = False

        elif action == 2:
            print ("Oh no, the ghost\'s power was strength!")
            print ("DEFEAT")
            print ("You\'r score is " + score)
            alive = False

        elif action == 3:
            print ("Oh no, the ghost wasn\'t friendly ")
            alive = False

    elif ghost_power == 4 and action == 3 :
        print ("Congratulations, The ghost was friendly!")
        score = score + 1
        ghost_door_choose(difficulty)

    elif ghost_power != action and ghost_power != 4 :
        if action == 1:
            print ("Congratulations, the ghost wasn\'t fast!")
            score = score + 1
             ghost_door_choose(difficulty)

        elif action == 2:
            print ("Congratulations, you defeated the ghost!")
            score = score +1
            ghost_door_choose(difficulty)

    elif ghost_power != action and ghost_power == 4 :
        if action == 1:
            print ("You ran away from a friendly ghost!")
            print ("Because you ran away for no reason, your score is now 0")
            score = 0
            ghost_door_choose(difficulty)
        elif action == 1:
            print ("You killed a friendly ghost!")
            print ("Your score is now 0 because you killed the friendly ghost")
            score = 0
            ghost_door_choose(difficulty)



                    #actual game loop

ask_difficulty()

while alive :
    ghost_door_choose(doors)
```

Comment: A bit too much code...

Comment: You are showing too much code. It would help the readers if you narrowed down to a [mcve].

Comment: You probably want a class if you want to share and update variables in various functions

Comment: At the beginning of each function, put `global ` and then a comma-separated list of the variables you wish to be able to change.  A class would be better here, but ...

Comment: idjaw, you'r probably right but I wasn't sure how to describe or just put a bit of the code to explain myself, so I put all of it just incase.

Comment: Please do not add "Solved" to the question once you got a fitting answer. As you have already marked an answer as the accepted answer, that's all you need to do. While a "thank you" is much appreciated, at this site we do not do it in writing: Just upvote answers (and questions for that matter) if they are well written, on topic, and helpful. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
x=0
z=22
def func(x,y):
    y=22
    z+=1
    print x,y,z

func('x','y')
```

When you call `func` you will get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment`

To fix the error in our function, do:

```
x=0
z=22
def func(x,y):
    global z
    y=22
    z+=1
    print x,y,z
```

The `global` keyword allows a local reference to a global defined variable to be changed.

Notice too that the local version of `x` is printed, not the global version. This is what you would expect. The ambiguity is if there is no local version of a value. Python treats globally defined values as read only unless you use the `global` keyword.

As stated in comments, a class to hold these variables would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Those variables at the top of your script are global and to set them in functions, you have to declare them global in the function. As a smaller example,

```
score = 0
alive = True

def add_score(value):
    """Add value to score"""
    global score
    score += value

def kill_kill_kill():
    global alive
    alive = False
```

The next step is to create classes, which can get complicated. For instance, if you want to track score by user but a user can have multiple characters which each have their own aliveness, you would start to build classes to represent those things.

Answer (score 0):

The global keyword may be what you are looking for.

For example in the following code.

```
some_variable = 10

def some_function():
    global some_variable
    some_variable = 20
```

This would result in some_variable (in the global scope) referring to the value of 20. Where as it would remain at 10 (in the global scope) without the use of the global keyword.

More on global and local variables [here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php).

Comment: I've solved the problem used by the not too good but slightly easier global keyword. I appreciate the help, and no longer require any more suggestions or answers.

Answer (score 0):

A function has its own variable scope - this is true for many languages. This means that once the function finishes executing, the variables cease to exist (and Python's garbage collection will clean them up).

The old-school (and generally frowned upon, not necessarily fairly) way of doing this is to use Global Variables. These are variables you declared outside the scope of the function, usually at the beginning of your source, and can be used throughout your program's various functions and classes.

There are good reasons people don't use global variables much, from performance issues through to getting them confused with locally scoped variables, but they are a quick and easy way to keep information and access it throughout your program.

To use a global, you need to declare within the function that you are using that variable, like this:

```
MyGlobal="This is a global variable"
def MyFunction():
    global MyGlobal
    MyGlobal += " and my function has changed it"
if __name__=="__main__":
    print MyGlobal
    MyFunction()
    print MyGlobal
```

Having said this, the usual way to pass information to and from functions is to use arguments and return values - this is a better design methodology, and the one usually taught. This is more a design method than a change to your code; you write your program with keeping global variables down to an absolute minimum.

To take the above example, this would change our code to the following:

```
def MyFunction(MyArg):
    MyArg+=" and my function has given me a new version of it"
    return MyArg
if __name__=="__main__":
    MyVariable="This is a variable"
    print MyVariable
    MyVariable = MyFunction(MyVariable)
    print MyVariable
```

Note that this is much more flexible - I can use it as I have above, to change the value of MyVariable, but I could also use the same function to return the new value to a different variable, keeping the original intact.

I hope this helps, sorry if I was a tad verbose.